# General matrix theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $0 \leq r \leq $ min($m,n$) is an integer. The following are equivalent:

(a) Rank($A$) = $r$

(b) Im($A$) = Span($A$) is an $r$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$

(c) The dimension of Null($A$) is $n-r$.

(d) The solution set of $Ax = b$ has dimension $n-r$

(e) $A$ has an $r$-minor of nonzero determinant, but every $(r+1)$-minor has determinant zero

(f) $A$ has an invertible $r$-minor, but every $(r+1)$-minor is singular

(g) Rank($A^T$) = $r$

(h) $A$ has exactly $r$ pivot positions

(i) $A$ has exactly $r$ linearly independent columns

(j) There are exactly $n-r$ columns of $A$ that is a linear combination of other columns of $A$.

Reminds you of the Invertible matrix theorem? I thought that the invertible matrix theorem is a somewhat special case of a more general theorem. That is the case when $M$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $r$. This is my question: Can you think of points that should be added to the list?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "invertible matrix theorem?" The theorem which says a matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is nonzero?

Comment: See either of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html Any theorem that has a striking similarity to that is something that I would call the "invertible matrix theorem".

Comment: Are you getting at the fact that if $m=n=r$ then you have a bunch of properties of an invertible matrix, e.g., $Rank(A)=n$, $im(A)$ is all of $\mathbb{R^n}$, dimension of the null space is 0, etc

Comment: I am asking if you can think of additional equivalent formulations of “$A$ is a matrix of rank $r$”.